# How to call axios from other folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios

I want to create new folder name `services` in that folder will include all `axios` action and I'm using vue here. Heres what I try..

my save function

```
save() {
  const CaseController = require("../services/gantt");
  CaseController.create(this.data);
},
```

my service file

```
const axios = () => import("../plugins/axios");

exports.create = async () => {
  return axios
    .get("/")
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .finally(() => {});
};
```

my plugins file

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
```

but when I try, I got an error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: axios.get is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this with

```
const axios = require("axios");
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

exports.create = async () => {
  instance
    .get("/")
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .finally(() => {});
};
```

so, instead import the `axios` from `plugins` folder, use it directly from `services`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've defined `axios` as `() => import("../plugins/axios");`, so it's a function, which does not have a `.get` method.  Further, using import as a function makes it return a promise. You need to do:

```
const axios = import("../plugins/axios");

exports.create = async () => {
  return (await axios)
    .get("/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {});
};
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but still i got same error

Comment: Try doing `const axios = import('../plugins/axios').default` or `import axios from '../plugins/axios'`

Comment: using `default` i got `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')` if using the second  `exports is not defined`

Comment: Oh that's it then - I forgot, when you use `import` as a function it returns a promise.  I'll update the answer

Comment: i got this `_context.sent.get is not a function`

Comment: are you using Internet Explorer by chance?

Comment: im using chrome